# Is there a way in flutter to let the pageview skip the screens in between the current screen and the new selected screen?

Tags: flutter, flutter-pageview

I have a PageView with 5 screens in it, when I start at screen [0], and animateToPage over to screen [4], it loads all the screens between them as well and also shows them briefly.

The consequence is that initState is called on each of those 'in-between' screens that are only very briefly shown on screen in the animateToPage animation, which is what I don't want.

Is there anyway to skip the 'in-between' pages, or just not let them load at all while the animateToPage is playing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was hoping flutter had made something for this but apparently not. Thanks for the link it is indeed a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 3):

use "jumpToPage" instead of "animateToPage"
Or use "PageController" like that image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOqUx.png)